# Является ли значение которое находится в регистре ESP процессора виртуальным адресом, или же чисто физическим?

Tags: c++, память, стек

Я знаю что процессу в ОС предоставляется свое виртуальное адресное пространство, адреса которого преобразуются в физические с помощью MMU процессора. Но я так и не разобрался со стеком (который вместе с кучей находятся в виртуальном адресном пространстве). Внутри процессора находиться регистр ESP указывающий на вершину стека. Так вот, вопрос: адрес, вершины стека находящийся непосредственно в регистре ESP является таким же виртуальным адресом как и адреса объектов в куче, или же напрямую физическим??? 
А так же, может ли случится такая ситуация что данные в стеке определенного потока исполнения программы будут разбиты на несколько частей и будут находиться в физической RAM в разных местах (например на разных физических страницах, если можно так выразиться?) ?
Проходит ли значение лежащее в регистре ESP преобразование виртуальный адрес -> физический адрес???

Comment: esp - адрес в виртуальной памяти. Теоретически https://dev64.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/interrupts-exceptions-reference/#interrupt-12 всё может быть.

Answer (score 4):

Адресное пространство виртуальное, и все адреса виртуальные, в т.ч. и то что лежит в ESP.

Вы можете в ESP записать любой адрес какой захотите, и пользоваться им (лишь бы не было исключений).

На 64-разрядной машине физические адреса 64-разрядные, и Вы их никак не запишете в 32-разрядный ESP.

Comment: Т.е ситуация когда переменные лежащие в стеке одна за другой с точки зрения программиста, могут лежать в физической памяти очень далеко друг от друга, возможна и очень вероятна?

Comment: @liberventum, память делится на страницы, обычно размером 4К, адреса начала которых кратны размеру. Поэтому все переменные, которые находятся в одной виртуальной странице в физической памяти также расположены рядом

Answer (score 0):

1. Адрес в регистре ESP является -  виртуальным адресом.

Кроме случая реального режима. `mov eax,esp` можно выполнить в реальном режиме и даже можно менять лимит для сегмента стека (переключить в линейный 32-битный режим), но современные ОС не работают с реальным режимом, потому что в этом режиме невозможно контролировать защиту и разделение процессора и памяти между процессами.

2. А так же, может ли случится такая ситуация что данные в стеке определенного потока исполнения программы будут разбиты на несколько частей и будут находиться в физической RAM в разных местах?

Может, но для каждой конкретной операции (выполнении команды ЦП) страница будет одна, т.к. данные "выровняны" по границам двойного слова (4 байта), и обращение гарантировано идёт к странице 1 или к странице 2 но не к обеим страницам одновременно (т.к. размер страницы делится на 4 без остатка). Конфликт можно создать искуственно, если обратится к обеим страницам одновременно (как для стека так и не для стека) - будет исключение Interrupt 17—Alignment Check Exception (#AC), поэтому рекомендуют делать выравнивание структур. Случайно это не случится.

3. Проходит ли значение лежащее в регистре ESP преобразование виртуальный адрес -> физический адрес?

Да проходит. Как - через каталог страниц (cr3). Скорее всего каталог кешируется процессором, операции суммирования выполняются очень быстро, тут пробемы нет.

Comment: Даже в реальном режиме разделены физические и виртуальные адреса. Да, физический и линейный адреса в нем совпадают - но сегменты-то никуда не делись...